# Proving the Poisson integral formula and Schwarz formula on the unit disk using a Mobius transformation

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I'm supposed to prove the Poisson integral formula $$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\mathbb{D}}\text{Re}\left(\frac{w+z}{w-z}\right)\frac{f(w)}{w}dw,$$ where $U$ is an open set such that $\overline{\mathbb{D}}\subseteq U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, and $f\in H(U)$.

I want to prove this using a Möbius transformation $\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$, where $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disk.

My Möbius transformation is the following.$$T_{z_0}(z) = \frac{z_0 - z}{1 - \overline{z_0}z}$$

So far I have been able to compute $$(f\circ T_{z_0})(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\mathbb{D}}f\left(\frac{z_0-w}{1-\overline{z_0}w}\right)\frac{dw}{w},$$ but now I'm stuck. I don't see how I can prove the formula from here on.

The next part of my question is to prove from this the Schwarz formula:
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\mathbb{D}}\frac{w+z}{w-z}\frac{\text{Re}f(w)}{w}dw + i\ \text{Im}f(0), \qquad z\in\mathbb{D}.$$They put a hint on the worksheet to use $$g(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\mathbb{D}}\frac{w+z}{w-z}\frac{\text{Re}f(w)}{w}dw $$ and the Poisson formula to show that $f-g$ is constant on $\mathbb{D}$.

I'm completely stuck with this exercise. Any hints on how I can continue?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the first part of your question: notice that $T_{z_0}$ interchanges points $0$ and $z_0$ hence
$$
f(z_0) = f(T_{z_0}(0)) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}}f(T_{z_0}(w))\frac{dw}{w}
$$
by the simple Cauchy formula. Next make change of variables $u = T_{z_0}(w)$, then
$$
u = \frac{z_0 - w}{1 - \bar{z_0}w}, \quad w = \frac{z_0 - u}{1 - \bar{z_0}u}, \quad dw = \frac{-1+ |z_0|^2}{(1 - \bar{z_0}u)^2}du
\\
f(z_0)  = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}}f(u)\frac{\frac{-1+ |z_0|^2}{(1 - \bar{z_0}u)^2}du}{\frac{z_0 - u}{1 - \bar{z_0}u}} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}}f(u)\frac{(-1+ |z_0|^2)du}{(1 - \bar{z_0}u)(z_0 - u)}
\\
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}}f(u)\frac{(-1+ |z_0|^2)du}{(\bar u - \bar{z_0})(z_0 - u)u} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}}f(u)\frac{(1 - |z_0|^2)du}{|z_0- u|^2u},
$$
which is the required form since
$$
\Re\left(\frac{u + z_0}{u - z_0}\right) = \frac{1 - |z_0|^2}{|u - z_0|^2}.
$$

UPD: to deal with the second problem, rewrite the complex intagrals in the real form, i.e. write
$$
f(z) =   \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}}\Re\left(\frac{w + z}{w - z}\right)\frac{f(u)du}{u} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(w)\Re\left(\frac{w + z}{w - z}\right)d\phi,\quad w = e^{i\phi};
\\
g(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}}\frac{w + z}{w - z}\Re\left(f(u)\right)\frac{du}{u} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\Re(f(w))\frac{w + z}{w - z}d\phi,\quad w = e^{i\phi}.
$$
From this we see that
$$
\Re (f(z)) = \Re(g(z)) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\Re(f(w))\Re\left(\frac{w + z}{w - z}\right)d\phi.
$$
Hence $f - g$ is purely imaginary analytic function. The only such function is constant. To calculate this constant put $z = 0$. It gives $g(0) =\Re(f(0))$, therefore $f(z) - g(z) = i\Im(f(0))$.

Comment: I think you forgot a square on the last line,  but besides from that, thank you for the inside, but I don't se why u and w have basically the same equation. Also do you have any idea how to work out the second part? @Pavel

Comment: Oh, you are right, I've added the square. Variables $u$ and $w$ are calculated by the same equation simply because $T_{z_0}(T_{z_0}(w)) = w$ for every $w$.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to work on the second part? I have problems applying the formula to the function f-g.

Comment: @ChessBaker251, I've added the answer to the second part of your question. The key is parametrization $w = e^{i\phi}$ and the corresponding change of variables.